# Performance with dynamically sized arrays in C++ MSVC vs GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, memory

Today a little argument erupted over the following code line in a fairly time critical piece of C++ that was running.

```
void func(std::string& str)
{
    ...
    uint8_t buffer[str.size() + 10];
    ...
}
```

Now obviously you can compile this in C as the standard supports dynamically sized arrays.  However GCC C++ seems to allow this kind of construct through some kind of an extension.  MSVC doesn't allow this kind of statement, so we were a bit puzzled.

- Does GCC allocate it at declaration time and is this allocation done on the stack?  Is it syntactic sugar for a dynamic allocation, like say using *new* to create an array?
- Is there are performance penalty for using a dynamically sized array over say a static one, given that a static one would be allocated in the prologue?

Comment: "_Now obviously you can't compile this in C as it's a dynamically sized array._" As far as I know: this is wrong. VLAs are allowed in C, by a standard. They are not allowed in C++, but some compilers (like GCC) provide extensions, that allow such behavior (as far as I could guess: using the same methods as one implements in C).

Comment: edit to change "obviously you can't" to "obviously you can"  

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58848183/dynamic-array-on-stack-vla-vs-heap-performance